# How to show the whole file name while using .htaccess to list files in a directory?

Tags: apache-http-server, html, htaccess

My `.htaccess` file looks like this :

```
Options +Indexes
```

When I look at the directory from my browser, it looks like this:

[image]

File names that are too long are truncated, how can I make it show the whole file name?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Easy! Just use the Apache [`IndexOptions`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_autoindex.html#indexoptions) directive in addition to `Options +Indexes` in the `.htaccess` file.

In your case this would be simple enough to show the full names of files:

```
Options +Indexes
<IfModule mod_autoindex.c>
  IndexOptions NameWidth=*
</ifModule>
```

The key for you is the `NameWidth` value which when set to a wildcard value of `*` will show the full length of the file and directory names.

[This site has some great examples](http://www.daveperrett.com/articles/2008/12/29/styling-apache-directory-listings-with-mod_autoindex/) on how to better customize and style your directory listings with `IndexOptions`. Ditto with [this site’s examples](https://perishablepress.com/better-default-directory-views-with-htaccess/) as well.